# MVC WCF Exception metadata was not handled by user code

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am programming both MVC Web application and WCF application to connect them together and both of them work perfectly,however after connecting them I get an exception in mvc application and the exception Exactly:

> "System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException" occurred in EntityFramework.dll, but was this not processed in the user code.

Additonal information the main webapplication rule is to add and manage user with asp.net Entity using two data base connection the locaö database and the Remote datavase.
the Wcf application connected to the remote database and it is role to transmit information from the webapplication to the remote database.
the webapplication without the connection with the WCF work Perfectly but after I add the Reference to my WCF it stop working with this exception.
inner error:

> The scheme is not valid. Error:
>   The assignment of the CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'tab_OnlineUserClaim'. Previously found CLR type
>
> 'ELVIRA_Userverwaltung.ServiceReference1.tab_OnlineUserClaim', newly found CLR type 'Userverwaltung.Models.tab_OnlineUserClaim'. The assignment of the CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'tab_OnlineUserLogin'. Previously found CLR type  'ELVIRA_Userverwaltung.ServiceReference1.tab_OnlineUserLogin', newly found CLR type 'Userverwaltung.Models.tab_OnlineUserLogin'.

---

Answer (score 0):

This means that the application is unable to load the EDMX.

- You might have changed the MetadataArtifactProcessing property of the
  model to Copy to Output Directory.
- The connection string could be wrong. I know you say you haven't changed it, but if you have changed other things (say, the name of an
  assembly), it could still be wrong.
- You might be using a post-compile task to embed the EDMX in the assembly, which is no longer working for some reason.

In short, there is not really enough detail in your question to give an accurate answer, but hopefully these ideas should get you on the right track.

Comment: I am adding the conecntionstring manually and i am pretty sure that is 100% true.

Comment: in webapplication i use Ado.net and in WCF i use Linq and also i edit the post with more information

Comment: EF collision happens only when two classes have the same name AND the same set of parameters.

Comment: sure because i am connecting the same database

Comment: EF matches on class name and class properties. So  just change the property names on one of the EF objects keep distinct names not same name.

Comment: Don't use classes with the same name - EF uses only class names to identify the type mapped in EDMX (namespaces are ignored) - it is a convention to allow mapping classes from different namespaces to single model. The solution for your problem is to name your classes in BLL differently.